# ¿Qué significa madruguete?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, méxico

Encontré esta palabra mientras estaba leyendo *[Instrucciones para Vivir en Mexico](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2766862-instrucciones-para-vivir-en-m-xico)* por Jorge Ibarguengoitia (una colección de artículos escritos para el periodico *Excelsior* entre 1969 a 1976), y no la entiendo, ni tampoco su explicación del significado.

¿Cómo se usa **madruguete** actualmente en Mexico?

Ibarguengoitia la usa describir el "precandidato" que se suspecha ser el "tapado" o el "verdadero gallo," eligido por un puesto alto por los lideres del PRI, pero en realidad no es. Una persona que se despierta demasiado temprano es un buen analogo.

¿Sería buena la traducción "early-riser"?

Yo nunca había oído o leído esta palabra. Al tratar de adivinar su significado, me ecuentro con tres o cuatro alternativas irreductibles. Son éstas:

> Cuando hay varios que creen ser el tapado, y uno de ellos, que sabe que es el verdadero gallo--porque se lo han dicho de arriba--, se adelanta--es decir, de madruguete--y hace que sus adeptos salgan a la calle con mantas y hagan circular volantes que digan 'clamor popular po Fulano.' (pg. 173)
>
> Madruguete también puede ser cuando hay varios que creen ser el tapado y otro, que sabe que no lo es, se adelanta--otra vez mantas y volantes--a ver si pega. Puede ocurrir que el centro, temeroso de que se note que lo agarraron cojeando, dé por buenos los telegramas y apoye la precandidatura del madrugador.
>
> Al tapado que no es en realidad el tapado, porque le cae mal a uno que esta muy arriba, lo proponen las organizaciones antes de tiempo, por ordenes expresas del centro. En este case, el madruguete occure cuando el mismo centro dice: 'este es madruguete, porque todavia ni sale la convocatoria'. El tapado es el quemado.

Comment: ¿podrías darnos más contexto? Normalmente refiere a alguien que se despierta muy temprano, pero puede que en otros contextos tenga otro significado

Comment: Madrugar es levantarse temprano, pero yo soy de españa de toda la vida y eso de madruguete es la primera vez que lo oigo (mejor dicho, que lo leo) en mi vida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré algo en el diccionario de [Oxford](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/spanish-english/madruguete) que no me ayudó mucho porque es súper británica la traducción (y yo no entiendo siempre esa versión del inglés): "le tendieron / hicieron un madruguete — they stole a march on him."

Luego encontré algo mejor, en un [blog](http://swearindf.blogspot.com/2008/03/madruguete.html), "Effective Swearing in D.F.: Towards a Manual of Communication for English Speakers visiting Mexico City":

> "Al que madruga, Dios le ayuda" (God helps those who get up early). Madrugada is the time after midnight and before sunrise. **Madrugar** in its intransitive form means to get up at that time, an activity that is seen in Mexico as a sign of will power, righteousness and good spirit. However, when madrugar is used in a transitive way, i.e. madrugar a alguien, it means to take advantage of that person but moving fast and stealthily. Madruguete is a furtive action.
>
> Pancho: "Mi primo es muy madrugador." (My cousin is an early riser.)
> Poncho: "¡Sí, ya me dijeron que te dio baje con la gordita de la tienda! ¡Qué **madruguete**!" (Indeed! I heard he moved faster than you with the corner store clerk! You didn't even see it coming!)

Me parece que "You didn't even see it coming!" (No te lo esperabas, es decir, no tenías la menor idea que esto es lo que iba a pasar) es la parte importante.  Encontré un montón de artículos de periódico que usan este termino, y lo que tienen en común es que alguien se queja o señala con cierta admiración alguna acción política que utilizó el elemento de sorpresa para una maniobra o una declaración a la prensa.

Me parece que hay un elemento de *emboscada* o ataque de sorpresa.  Parece que la sorpresa pega todo de pronto temprano por la mañana, ya sea literal or figurativamente.

Creo que es una maniobra, una jugada sorpresiva, en algún conflicto.

Comment: Just to confirm that "to steal a march on" has indeed the same sense as the  blogger outlines, to take advantage of someone by moving faster than them.

Comment: @mdewey - No argument with that -- but I wanted to get some additional clarity because "to steal a march on" wasn't very helpful to at least this U.S. English speaker.

Comment: Gracias por la clarificacion, creo que ya entiendo. Pensaba que el "madruguete" fuera la persona, no la accion. El "madrugador" es la persona que hace el "madruguete." De hecho, Google Translate traduce "madrugador" como "early riser," pero no tiene ningun traduccion para "madruguete."

Answer (score 2):

"Dar madruguete" es cuando alguien muy "vivo" aprovecha la confusión o la circunstancia y actúa rápidamente aprovechando que los demás están descuidados. Ejemplo: en el fútbol *soccer* a veces cobran una falta rápido aprovechando que el otro equipo apenas se está acomodando. Esto es "dar madruguete".